# What does 'Checking out files' stat indicate while switching to master branch in Git world?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

I am using git bash.
I created a brand new local git repository from a brand new public repository ( means it just had .gitIgnore file. no code)
I branched off from my local master repository to a new repository 'FromClearcase' using:

```
git branch FromClearcase
git checkout FromClearcase
```

I pasted 49 files of code into my local git repository.

Following shows all these 49 files as untracked.

```
git status
```

Next I do following:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Migrating from CC"
```

I get following message "On branch FromClearcase nothing to commint, working directory clean" when it do following
    git status

Next is where the I have a surprise observation. I want to switch back to local master branch to perform a merge.

```
git checkout master
```

I get following message:
**Checking out files: 100% (49/49), done.**
*Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'*

I am unable to comprehend the message in first line. Why does 49/49 stat apears when I am trying to switch? 'git checkout master' must not trigger checking out of code that belongs to a different branch. What is happenning ?

Comment: what operating system are you using? I havent seen this before. It might be a check to see if all of your files are commited before checking out master (so you dont lose any changes)

Comment: I am on Windows 7 enterprise

Comment: When you do a `git branch FromClearcase` it only creates the branch. It does not switch to it. So from what you say, it seems like you have added files to the local `master` branch and not the newly created `FromClearcase`. @DolphinJava Are you sure you have written all the performed steps in your question?

Comment: @gravetii took the words right out of my mouth :) No evidence that the OP was _ever_ on the FromClearcase branch: he just created it "in the background" and then ignored it.

Comment: @gravetii Your comment pointed out a mistake in typing the question. I did switched to the FromClearcase branch. Updated the question. Sorry about it.

Comment: @DolphinJava You haven't changed `master` in any way for all I know, since it's up to date with `origin/master` though.

Comment: @gravetii After git checkout master, I did git merge FromClearcase; And it successfully merged. The resulting messages included: __updating 5n234... Checking out files: 100% (49/49), done. Fast-forward__ This was followed by list of files that were merged. and create mode messages

Comment: Well, then all seems good except the `Checking out files` thing.

Comment: yup that exactly made me curious :)

Comment: @matt Did you happen to see that message in git earlier? :-). I haven't seen it ever.

Comment: My git version is Git-1.9.4-preview20140611

Comment: @DTSCode I get the message occasionally on git 1.7.9.5 on Ubuntu - something happens inside git that causes it to do this.  Neither branch nor repo are consistent in any way, and there are no local changes nor untracked files

Comment: hmmm might be a bug then. let me see if i kind something in the repo

Answer (score 2):

Your git client is just telling you that it performed 49 file operations to check out the tree you asked for. What it doesn't tell you is that in this case, all 49 operations were removals (it removed the 49 files that you committed in your other branch). The confusion arises because most people read "checking out files" as if it was referring exclusively to create/copy operations.